# How can i show large image in the starting of activity with minimum time?

Tags: java, android, mobile-development

In my wallpaper android app I have first activity in which user selects any one image and go to the next activity, and in second activity I show preview of image. It is loading and taking long time. How can I reduce the loading time? on the same network obviously.
how can I preload this image?
I used Glide as well as Picasso no difference in loading time.

Comment: try to load a preview or thumbnail of that image in process of loading the actual image. also do some research about progressive jpeg. you can reduce the loading time but you can work on UX.

Comment: yeah i tried to load thumbnail and it worked also. But not satisfied with image quality as it will be more blurr as the screen size will increase...will search about progressive jpeg though..thanks

Comment: Found that it could be done with fresco library...will report back if it works...thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

**Simple use cases with Glide's generated API will look something like this:**
    `ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
    GlideApp.with(this).load("IMAGE URL").into(imageView);`

Comment: Yeah did the same thing..but as i said image is big so it is taking around 10 sec to load image with my fast wifi connection. So what i can do where can i cach the image as it has to be shown immediately after the activity starts...thanks

Comment: There are some very good wallpaper apps on playstore which shows high quality image on the go and even allow user to swipe for next image with neglegible time in loading it from server...

Comment: use local image file